# Algorithm for computing current speed (not just average)?

Tags: algorithm

Often, one wants to determine the *current* speed of some process (computation, download, network transfer, rendering, ...) consisting of many steps, the duration of which is measured.  However, when taking just the last measurement, the display is unstable, so a common way is to smooth over some period.  On the other hand, this leads to the display "lagging behind" when the speed suddenly changes, so the displayed speed changes smoothly, while the underlying process has **changed it speed very suddenly**.

Given a long sequence of measurements of such steps (e.g. transferred blocks, iterations of a computation), I want to

- display the current speed,
- averaged over as long as possible, but
- not averaging over periods during which the speed changed.

Graphically, this means I want to compute the current slope of a piecewise linear curve with noise, while automatically detecting the segment ends (slope/speed changes).

I can come up with algorithms myself, I can also apply some knowledge from geometrical curve fitting, but I wonder if there are non-trivial go-to solutions to this (seemingly very common) particular problem?  Any references, textbook examples, open source implementations that stand out?

Comment: Get a volume of last piece of processed task. Divide it by taken time. This is called derivative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative.

Comment: I know, thanks, I already mentioned "slope", which is closely related to the first derivative.

Comment: When dealing with computers discrete world, the closest you can get to an instant speed is to take the time between two continious units of whatever you want to meassure and the difference is the instant speed meassured in units per time unit (milliseconds or nanoseconds most likely). For this not to hit performance you can choose to take the meassure every N number of processed units.

Comment: The key phrase is "the current slope of a piecewise linear curve with noise", and some other comments apparently didn't recognize that.

Comment: @Juan: I can come up with several possible ways to do that, that is not the problem. Simply put I wanted to know a known, optimal algorithm for computing N (not too small / too unstable, not too large / averaging over different speeds).

Comment: The problem you're left with here is, in fact, the reason we're averaging on the first place - how to distinguish (a) a "spike" that corresponds to something spurious from (b)  a spike due to an actual change in the underlying trend?  As we can't predict the future, the trade-off we generally make is the latency you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but maybe useful anyway:

You can do a linear regression over some accumulated samples. This gives you the current speed, and an expected value for the next sample, assuming that speed and noise didn't change.

If the next sample lies inside the expected range, update the regression parameters (can be done incrementally), thus refining the speed value and narrowing the expected range for the next sample.

If the sample lies outside of the expected, you probably had a speed change, and you restart the regression there (maybe including a few recent samples not to start from zero).

I didn't go deep into the math, but maybe the new-speed decision can be based on a degrading correlation coefficient instead of / in addition to the outlier check.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am getting comments that point out obvious solutions, I'll describe my current idea(s) here, which I would like to check against literature / existing good implementations:

- define a minimum period of time to average over (say, 5 seconds)
- define a maximum such period (say, 1 minute)
- during the process:

  - push new measurements into a FIFO
  - pop old measurements from the FIFO if their age exceeds the above maximum time
  - on every display update

    - initialize display period with minimum period (and compute speed from that period)
    - enlarge display period while it is smaller than the FIFO and the next sample **"matches"** the speed within the display period
    - update the display

The "matching" is the crucial part here; mathematically speaking, one would like to know the probability of the sample in question to come from the same distribution.  It is probably best to assume a normal distribution, but I have even examples in mind that are not monomodal.